# Raspberry Pi Updates Server for Offline (No Internet) Devices

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, updates

Looking for some advice on an issue I have no idea how to tackle at the moment.

**Background:** Approx 100+ Raspberry Pi devices coming online in the next year. None of them will have internet access available once deployed in the field, only internal network communications will be allowed (Security Policy). These devices will be used across North America, Europe, Australia on an internal network to our company.

**Needed:** Some way to security patch these devices from a central system that could have an internet connection to download them as needed. Similar to a WSUS server for Windows OSes.

**Suggestions** on where to start???

Comment: Maybe using Ansible playbooks? If you are into server stuff https://serverfault.com/ may be good place.

Comment: IIRC, then RasPies use a simple Debianesque APT repository - there are many guides around on how to creat a local one!

Comment: Thanks for some starter info. I will check them out and see if it works for what I need. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

First, I would configure - by hand - a minimal version of [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) on one of the devices, then copy this image to 100 SD cards.

Second, I would write an [Ansible playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html) to further configure the devices, install software, create users, disable root login, upload SSH keys, etc. It doesn't have to be complex, just enough for an ordinary user to be able to login over SSH.

Now, the devices can be sent off to wherever they need to be. When there's a need to reconfigure, update the Ansible playbook and run it against all 100 of the devices. The only thing required for Ansible to work remotely is a working SSH login.

Comment: Didn't you miss the whole "offline" issue? Or is that built into this Ansible thing? I'll take a look...